# Performance issue while evaluating email address with a regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, email-validation, email-client

I am using below regular expression to validate email address.

```
/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/
```

Javascript Code:

```
var email = 'myname@company.com';

var pattern = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;

if(pattern.test(email)){
    return true;
}
```

The regex evaluates quickly when I provide the below invalid email:

```
aseflj#$kajsdfklasjdfklasjdfklasdfjklasdjfaklsdfjaklsdjfaklsfaksdjfkasdasdklfjaskldfjjdkfaklsdfjlak@company.com
```

(I added `#$` in the middle of the name)

However when I try to evaluate this email it takes too much time and the browser hangs.

```
asefljkajsdfklasjdfklasjdfklasdfjklasdjfaklsdfjaklsdjfaklsfaksdjfkasdasdklfjaskldfjjdkfaklsdfjlak@company.com1
```

(I added `com1` in the end)

I'm sure that the regex is correct but not sure why its taking so much time to evaluate the second example. If I provide an email with shorter length it evaluates quickly. See the below example

```
dfjjdkfaklsdfjlak@company.com1
```

Please help me fix the performance issue

Comment: Weirdest part is that using *dynamic programming*, one can evaluate every (regular) *regex* in *O(n)*. So the evaluation should be lightning fast.

Comment: Looks like the regex is no good. If you try it in [Regex101](https://regex101.com/#javascript) With your pattern and the test thats too long, you will see it stops after two seconds and tells you there's something wrong with your Regex, it then points you to this [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). My guess is that the time is increasing exponentially per character, due the way that pattern is designed.

Comment: Try this one, it should be the same I think `^(\w[\w.-]*@[\w.-]*\.\w{2,3})$`

Comment: See [this helpful page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) for good suggestions for email regexes.

Comment: Removing the `?` also seemed to fix the catastrophic backtracking issue (i.e. use `/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/` instead). I'm not sure if this is good enough for you, or if it fails any test cases. But it did solve the main performance problem in a trivial way. @James Hay's one might be even better, though.

Comment: @GregL Yours appears shorter in this case, 18 steps versus 26 for mine. Both improvements over the original which weighs in at 115924 steps!

Comment: @GregL: I'd drop the `?` in `[\.-]?`. That is one potential source of catastrophic backtracking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex runs into catastrophic backtracking. Since `[\.-]?` in `([\.-]?\w+)*` is optional, it makes the group degenerates to `(\w+)*`, which is a classic case of catastrophic backtracking.

Remove the `?` resolves the issue.

I also remove the redundant escape of `.` inside character class, and changed the regex a bit.

```
^\w+([.-]\w+)*@\w+([.-]\w+)*\.\w{2,3}$
```

Do note that many new generic TLDs have more than 3 characters. Even some of the gTLD before the expansion have more than 3 characters, such as `.info`.

And as it is, the regex also doesn't support internationalized domain name.